# Alternative to cross server query in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to do a cross-server query in SSIS and have been having a hard time figuring out how to do it. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT Name, Email
FROM Server1.dbo.table1
WHERE UniqueID IN (SELECT UniqueID FROM Server2.dbo.table2)
```

The inner query (which is on a separate database on a separate server) will return a small list of identifiers - no more than a few dozen. Instead of explicitly doing a cross-server query, I would like to do the following:

1. Fetch the inner query and save it in a variable (var1).
2. Execute a second query that like this:

```
SELECT Name, Email
FROM Server1.dbo.table1
WHERE UniqueID IN var1
```

I think this should be pretty simple to do, but I don't know how to implement it. I am comfortable setting up database connections and doing some configurations in the db source object. The parts I am not sure about is how to save the result set from the first query to a variable, and then how to use that variable in the second query. For example I think I need to pass it as a parameter, but I don't know if I have to format the result set into a list of comma separated values, or if I can just pass the object directly to the second query.

If someone could give me some pointers, or maybe even a couple screenshots to demonstrate how to set this up I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

you need two datasources and you have to use the lookup transformation to filter the Server1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other approaches too.

You could fetch the IDs as you propose, but fetch them as JSON.  eg

```
select concat('[', string_agg(UniqueID,','),']') from table2;
```

and then pass the resulting JSON string as a parameter:

```
SELECT Name, Email
FROM table1
WHERE UniqueID IN ( SELECT [Value] FROM openjson(@ids) )
```

Or load the IDs into a [temp table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/) on Server1, and reference them in your query.